# NullPointerException and coding

Tags: java, android

Hi I've made code for Setting menu.
This application is for Downloading SNS video files and
 this setting menu needs to have
function to change the SNS ID and the location of downloaded file.

I've made code that can change ID and show the location.

But the code `save.setText(path.toString());` shows **NullPointerException**.
(Attached LogCat of **Nullpointer**.)

Can you guys help me solve the **Nullpointer** problem 
and coding a code that changes the location of downloaded file?

===Guide.java===

```
package kr.co.lenonstudio.kakaovideo;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonRectangle;
import java.io.File;

public class Guide
  extends Fragment
{


    EditText save;
    EditText idedit;
    ButtonRectangle changebtn;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_guide, container, false);


        //initialize
        save=(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.savefolder);
        idedit=(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.settingid);
        changebtn=(ButtonRectangle)rootView.findViewById(R.id.change_btn);

        //insert save floder////
        File path=this.getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(null);
        save.setText(path.toString());
        ///////////////////////


        ///////////DB ID////////
        idedit.setText(Bus.getInstance().id);
        ////////////////////////

        //Listener
        changebtn.setOnClickListener(changebtnClickListener);

        return rootView;
    }

    View.OnClickListener changebtnClickListener=new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            DBsingle.getInstance().execSQL("update config set value='"+idedit.getText().toString()+"' where name='id'");
            Bus.getInstance().id=idedit.getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(Guide.this.getActivity(),"Succesfully Changed.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent=new Intent(Guide.this.getActivity(),Frame_main.class);
            startActivity(intent);


        }
    };

}
```

===LogCat===

```
02-18 11:36:26.960    2140-2140/kr.co.lenonstudio.kakaovideo E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: kr.co.lenonstudio.kakaovideo, PID: 2140
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.io.File.toString()' on a null object reference
        at kr.co.lenonstudio.kakaovideo.Guide.onCreateView(Guide.java:48)
....
```

Comment: What do you mean by changing the location of downloaded file?

Comment: @LukeSpringWalker I mean OnClickListener. If I press the button The Files aren't be saved in External Memory but the custom location

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs

```
getExternalFilesDir(null) return null if there is no external memory.
```

so first insert **external memory** and try again.

**Note : If you dont want to insert external memory then use**

```
getFilesDir ();
```

Hope this will helps you.

Answer (score 1):

your File object path is null instance on that you are calling `path.toString()` .

you have to pass your external directory address instead of `null`

```
File path=this.getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(null);
```

Comment: Actually passing null there is an acceptable option, and is usually not the root cause. Most commonly it's the missing permissing declaration, or an unavailable storage.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from here:

```
    File path=this.getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(null);
    save.setText(path.toString());
```

The `path.toString()` causes the nullpointer exception, because You don´t get the external storage path. path is null, what leads me to the possible thought, that You have not set the permission.

You need to set the permissions in Your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this documentation about `getExternalFilesDir` method

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html

And you should check if path is null and let a superior layer handle it.

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_guide, container, false);

    //initialize
    save=(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.savefolder);
    idedit=(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.settingid);
    changebtn=(ButtonRectangle)rootView.findViewById(R.id.change_btn);

    //insert save floder////
    File path=this.getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(null);

    if(path == null){

        return null;

    }

    save.setText(path.toString());
    ///////////////////////


    ///////////DB ID////////
    idedit.setText(Bus.getInstance().id);
    ////////////////////////

    //Listener
    changebtn.setOnClickListener(changebtnClickListener);

    return rootView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 File path=this.getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(null);
```

returns null because your external storage is not available (maybe not mounted). Check that the external storage is mounted (insert, extract or re-insert the sd card to fix).